# Gather info through several foreach and then export-csv at the end of script

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-to-csv

I have a script that scans all my servers in my domains and outputs to two separate CSV files - one simple and one extensive.

I write one line at the time to my csv.. This results in thousands of file-open and file-close.. I've lurked around and understand that I should first gather all the info and write it all in one sweep at the end of the script. But how do I do this with export-csv (preferably using a function)?

And is there a way I can use the same function for short and long list?

The script performs numerous tasks on each domain/server, but I've trimmed it down to this for your viewing pleasure:

```
$domains = "no","se","dk"

# Loop through specified forests
foreach ($domain in $domains) {

    # List all servers
    $servers = Get-QADComputer 

    # Looping through the servers
    foreach ($server in $servers) {

        # GENERATE LONGLIST #
        # Ping server
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server.name -count 1 -Quiet )
        {
            $Reachable = "Yes"

            # Fetch IP address
            $ipaddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Server.name)|select-object IPAddressToString -expandproperty IPAddressToString

            # Formatting output and export all info to CSV
            New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                SystemName = ($server.name).ToLower()
                Reachable = $Reachable
                Domain = $server.domain
                IPAddress = $IPAddress
                } | Select-Object SystemName,Domain,IPAddress| Export-Csv -Path "longexport.csv" -append    
        } 
        else # Can't reach server
        {
            $reachable = "No"
            $IPAddress = "Unknown"

            # Formatting output and export all info to CSV
            New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                SystemName = ($server.name).ToLower()
                Reachable = $Reachable
                Domain = $server.domain
                } | Select-Object SystemName,Domain,IPAddress| Export-Csv -Path "shortexport.csv" -append
        }
    }
}
```

(and let me just say that I know that I cannot do -append with export-csv, but I am using a function that let's me do this..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting the same amount of properties to each file so I'm not sure I understand why one of them is considered long and one short. Anyway, I suggest the following, don't assign all computers to a variable, it can take up a lot of RAM, instead use a streaming way (one object at a time) and use foreach-object. Also, since I find no difference in the files I output to the file at the end of each domain operation (one per domain). And with another twick you could write only once to the file.

```
$domains = "no","se","dk"

foreach ($domain in $domains) {

    Get-QADComputer -Service $domain -SizeLimit 0 | Foreach-Object {

        $reachable = Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -count 1 -Quiet

        if($reachable)
        {
            $IPAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($_.Name)|select-object IPAddressToString -expandproperty IPAddressToString
        }
        else
        {
            $IPAddress = $null
        }


        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                SystemName = $_.Name.ToLower()
                Reachable = $reachable 
                Domain = $_.Domain
                IPAddress = $IPAddress
        } | Select-Object SystemName,Domain,IPAddress 

    } | Export-Csv -Path export.csv -Append  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! "Long" pings the server and "short" doesn't. I forgot to remove the IPAddress from select object:) Is there a way to do different | Select-Object from the same object?

Comment: And one more thing.. I display a status bar with help of the $servers.length variable. Is there a similar thing I can do with this approach?

Comment: You can save the new object to a variable and pipe it to select and each time select different properties. Regarding $servers.length, you can't display it's length cause you're processing one name at a time. You could create a variable and increment it in each iteration and display its value.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining Shay! I do have a problem however.. I actually write to three different CSV's inside the former $servers loop. Can this be done with your approach?

Comment: How about writing all information to one file, when the scripts ends, you read back the file and based on your criteria you select the desired properties for each scenario and then exporting it to a separate file?

Comment: Sounds smart! This is the way to go. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to keep data in memory to prevent multiple file open/closes.

You can do this by adding your data to an array like this:

```
$myData = @()
$myData += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                SystemName = ($server.name).ToLower()
                Reachable = $Reachable
                Domain = $server.domain
                } | Select-Object SystemName,Domain,IPAddress
```

Then at the end of processing convert the array to CSV using `$myData | ConvertTo-CSV | Out-File C:\Data.csv` or just `$myData | Export-Csv C:\Data.csv`.

Comment: Thank you Andy! Will an array work similar to a psobject? Sorry if that is a noob question, but I am somewhat of a noob:)

Comment: @Sune No problemo, we all start somewhere ;-) Think of the array as a bucket (in memory) were can store your PSObjects. The PSObject is a single object, where as the array is a collection of objects. The `+=` operator adds your new PSobject to the list. When the loop completes you'll end up with an array full of your PSObjects.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but I chose Shay's because of the RAM issue. Thank you so much for your explanation though:):)