# Powershell list permissions for top of information store for all mailboxes in a specific object unit

Tags: powershell

Need an advise how to loop the following code to list all user's permissions  in a specific object unit:

```
 Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity username:\
```

There should something like this but need right way to put a loop here:

```
 Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit "ou=test,ou=internal,ou=net,dc=local,dc=net"  | Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity username:\ \\networkshare\mailboxpermissions.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a foreach loop after identifying your users.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | foreach { 
   Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_.Id 
}
```

Append `| Export-CSV x.csv` if needed. You may need to create custom objects for this, however. See [this helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383762/gather-info-through-several-foreach-and-then-export-csv-at-the-end-of-script).

Comment: Thank you! I came across to the following code but it does not work probably due to some syntax issue, need advise. `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit "ou=test,ou=internal,ou=net,dc=local,dc=net" | foreach { Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_.id }| Export-Csv \\networkshare\mailboxpermissions.csv`  I think I need to specify Identity in another way and also I need to specify that I need permissions for Top of Information Store. For a single script I just put username:\

Comment: I forgot to add that that error message is 'Cannot bing argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null

Comment: So I did a bit of research, and apparently you can just pipe directly to `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`. So first, make sure `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit "ou=test,ou=internal,ou=net,dc=local,dc=net"` is returning results (sanity check?). Then, run `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit "ou=test,ou=internal,ou=net,dc=local,dc=net" | Get-MailboxFolderPermission`. Let me know how that works.